# Can I serve a javascript file instead of index.html in my github pages site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github, github-pages

I want to serve a javascript file using github pages because using a CDN is too slow (it doesn't update immediately when there is a new version of the file). Is there a way to serve a javascript file instead of index.html when someone access my github pages url? Or alternatively is there a way such that index.html returns a javascript file as response instead of the usual html content?

Comment: /use/a/suburl/maybe.js?

Comment: @Jonasw I tried pushing a file.txt to an existing github page, but when I try to access (github page url)/file.txt it says file isn't found. It might be because it's not yet updated. In my experience index.html gets updated fast enough that's why I want to use index.html to make the updates reflect faster

Comment: if you want to update fast, rent your own server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the "raw" version link of the file. You get this link when you click on the "RAW" button.

**Example:**

GitHub File:

```
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js
```

Raw Link:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/master/src/core.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) version. This is a good option for single files.